# Delete non-consecutive values from a dataframe column

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Ind TIME  PREC  ET    PET   YIELD
0      1  1.21  0.02  0.02   0.00
1      2  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
2      3  0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
3      4  0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
4      5  0.00  0.05  0.07   0.00
5      6  0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
6      7  0.00  0.02  0.04   0.00
7      8  1.14  0.03  0.04   0.00
8      9  0.10  0.02  0.03   0.00
9     10  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
10    11  0.10  0.05  0.11   0.00
11    12  0.00  0.06  0.15   0.00
12    13  2.30  0.14  0.44   0.00
13    14  0.17  0.09  0.29   0.00
14    15  0.00  0.13  0.35   0.00
15    16  0.00  0.14  0.39   0.00
16    17  0.00  0.10  0.31   0.00
17    18  0.00  0.15  0.51   0.00
18    19  0.00  0.22  0.58   0.00
19    20  0.10  0.04  0.09   0.00
20    21  0.00  0.04  0.06   0.00
21    22  0.27  0.13  0.43   0.00
22    23  0.00  0.10  0.25   0.00
23    24  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
24    25  0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
25    26  0.43  0.04  0.15   0.00
26    27  0.17  0.06  0.23   0.00
27    28  0.50  0.02  0.04   0.00
28    29  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
29    30  0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
30    31  0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
31     1  6.48  1.97  5.10   0.03
32    32  0.00  0.22  0.70   0.00
33    33  0.00  0.49  0.88   0.00
```

In this dataframe column `'TIME'` shows ordinal day number in a year, and after the end of every month - an ordinal number of month in a year, which messes up all dataframe calculations, so, for this reason, I would like to drop all rows that contain month value. First, I tried to use `.shift()`:

`df = df.loc[df.TIME == df.TIME.shift() +1]`,

however, in this case, I delete twice as many rows as it supposed to be. I also tried to delete every value after the end of every month:

```
for i in indexes:
    df = df.loc[df.index != i],
```

where `indexes` is a list, containing row indexes after day value is equal to 31, 59, ... 365 or end of every month. However, in a leap year, these values would be different, and I could create another list for a leap year, but this method would be very non-pythonist. So, I wonder, is there any better way to delete non-consecutive values from a dataframe (excluding when one year ends and another one starts: 364, 365, 1, 2)? 
EDIT: I should, probably, add that there are twenty years in this dataframe, so this is how the dataframe looks like at the end of each year:

`TIME   PREC    ET   PET  YIELD
370   360   0.00  0.14  0.26   0.04
371   361   0.00  0.15  0.27   0.04
372   362   0.00  0.14  0.25   0.04
373   363   0.11  0.18  0.32   0.04
374   364   0.00  0.15  0.25   0.04
375   365   0.00  0.17  0.29   0.04
376    12  16.29  4.44  7.74   1.89
377     1   0.00  0.16  0.28   0.03
378     2   0.00  0.18  0.32   0.03
379     3   0.00  0.22  0.40   0.03`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df['TIME'].shift().fillna(0) <= df['TIME']]
```

Gives what you're looking for. You were almost there with

```
df.loc[df.TIME == df.TIME.shift() +1]
```

But you don't need to get rid of cases where `.shift` is smaller, because that's just the first of the month.

The addition of `.fillna(0)` takes care of the `NaN` in the first row of `df['TIME'].shift()`.

**Edit:**

For the end of year case, just be sure to also take those with a difference of 11, to catch where the 12th month ends.
That would give

```
df[(df['TIME'].shift().fillna(0) <= df['TIME']+11)]
```

**Edit2:**
By  the by, I checked solution runtimes, and the current  version(`df[~df.TIME.diff().le(-12)]`) of @piRSquared's seems to run fastest.

For completeness, of the one presented in this post and the original version posted by @piRSquared,
the former was a bit faster on datasets on the order of 10000 rows or fewer, the latter somewhat faster on those larger.

Comment: This method also works, however,  as, in @piRSquared  solution, rows with first days of a year disappear.

Comment: Thanks, @EFT. What does `<=` mean?

Comment: Less than or equal to.

Answer (score 2):

```
df

    TIME   PREC    ET   PET  YIELD
0    360   0.00  0.14  0.26   0.04
1    361   0.00  0.15  0.27   0.04
2    362   0.00  0.14  0.25   0.04
3    363   0.11  0.18  0.32   0.04
4    364   0.00  0.15  0.25   0.04
5    365   0.00  0.17  0.29   0.04
6     12  16.29  4.44  7.74   1.89
7      1   1.21  0.02  0.02   0.00
8      2   0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
9      3   0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
10     4   0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
11     5   0.00  0.05  0.07   0.00
12     6   0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
13     7   0.00  0.02  0.04   0.00
14     8   1.14  0.03  0.04   0.00
15     9   0.10  0.02  0.03   0.00
16    10   0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
17    11   0.10  0.05  0.11   0.00
18    12   0.00  0.06  0.15   0.00
19    13   2.30  0.14  0.44   0.00
20    14   0.17  0.09  0.29   0.00
21    15   0.00  0.13  0.35   0.00
22    16   0.00  0.14  0.39   0.00
23    17   0.00  0.10  0.31   0.00
24    18   0.00  0.15  0.51   0.00
25    19   0.00  0.22  0.58   0.00
26    20   0.10  0.04  0.09   0.00
27    21   0.00  0.04  0.06   0.00
28    22   0.27  0.13  0.43   0.00
29    23   0.00  0.10  0.25   0.00
30    24   0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
31    25   0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
32    26   0.43  0.04  0.15   0.00
33    27   0.17  0.06  0.23   0.00
34    28   0.50  0.02  0.04   0.00
35    29   0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
36    30   0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
37    31   0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
38     1   6.48  1.97  5.10   0.03
39    32   0.00  0.22  0.70   0.00
40    33   0.00  0.49  0.88   0.00
```

Look at the diffs in `TIME`.  Drop the rows where diff is between -360 and -1

```
df[~df.TIME.diff().le(-12)]

    TIME  PREC    ET   PET  YIELD
0    360  0.00  0.14  0.26   0.04
1    361  0.00  0.15  0.27   0.04
2    362  0.00  0.14  0.25   0.04
3    363  0.11  0.18  0.32   0.04
4    364  0.00  0.15  0.25   0.04
5    365  0.00  0.17  0.29   0.04
7      1  1.21  0.02  0.02   0.00
8      2  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
9      3  0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
10     4  0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
11     5  0.00  0.05  0.07   0.00
12     6  0.00  0.03  0.05   0.00
13     7  0.00  0.02  0.04   0.00
14     8  1.14  0.03  0.04   0.00
15     9  0.10  0.02  0.03   0.00
16    10  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
17    11  0.10  0.05  0.11   0.00
18    12  0.00  0.06  0.15   0.00
19    13  2.30  0.14  0.44   0.00
20    14  0.17  0.09  0.29   0.00
21    15  0.00  0.13  0.35   0.00
22    16  0.00  0.14  0.39   0.00
23    17  0.00  0.10  0.31   0.00
24    18  0.00  0.15  0.51   0.00
25    19  0.00  0.22  0.58   0.00
26    20  0.10  0.04  0.09   0.00
27    21  0.00  0.04  0.06   0.00
28    22  0.27  0.13  0.43   0.00
29    23  0.00  0.10  0.25   0.00
30    24  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
31    25  0.00  0.04  0.05   0.00
32    26  0.43  0.04  0.15   0.00
33    27  0.17  0.06  0.23   0.00
34    28  0.50  0.02  0.04   0.00
35    29  0.00  0.03  0.04   0.00
36    30  0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
37    31  0.00  0.04  0.08   0.00
39    32  0.00  0.22  0.70   0.00
40    33  0.00  0.49  0.88   0.00
```

Comment: That's a good short solution, but I need exactly the opposite: to delete months and leave days only. So, this: `df[df.TIME.diff().between(1, 366)]` works, however, all rows with the 1st day of a year also deletes.

Comment: Include data with the first of the year.

Comment: @SergeyGulbin The `~` is important, negating the selection. The version posted in your comment is a bit more straightforward, though.

Comment: @piRSquared, @ETF, my bad, with `~` code deletes months and leaves days, however, the problem I described earlier with first days of a year is still actual.

Comment: @SergeyGulbin it was a matter of fine tuning the thresholds to account for large enough diffs.